# RTK Query - Delete cached data upon cacheEntryAdded

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Currently we have an api endpoint that requests a single 'Group' via ID.

We have a WebSocket subscription set up, and in the onCacheEntryAdded definition, we handle cases where that Group is updated, or deleted.

When we receive an update message from the websocket, we trigger the following;

```
updateCachedData((draft) => {
  draft = response;
}
```

Which updates the entry, as expected.

However, what is the approach we should use if we want to remove the entry entirely? Upon 'delete' messages from the websocket, I would assume I could simply set draft as undefined, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
updateCachedData((draft) => {
  draft = response;
}
```

actually does not update anything here in the first place.

`updateQueryResults` has the same rules as `produce` from `immer` or normal `createSlice` case reducers: you can modify the object in `state` (or `draft` in this case), but you cannot reassign the variable itself. If you want to do that, you have to

```js
updateCachedData((draft) => {
  return response;
}
```

instead.

In the same fashion, you can

```js
updateCachedData((draft) => {
  return null;
}
```

too, but that will not remove the full cache entry, it will only set the `data` to `null`. (`undefined` won't work!)

The cache entry will only be removed once there is no more component using it (by not using it with `useQuery`) - and then it will be removed automatically after 60 seconds.

Comment: This works brilliantly, returning null is totally fine in this case :) Thanks as always for the answer, and thanks for a brilliant package :)